# Is the distance between the USB-C ports on the 2019 Macbook Pro 16" exactly the same as on earlier 15" models?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb

Asking so I know whether an older USB hub will fit.

Comment: Which hub, specifically, do you have? The Hyperdrive?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it fits perfectly! I checked today with a new MacBook Pro 16" and the distance between the two USB-C ports is the same.

Comment: What is the distance in millimetres, edge-to edge basically? 

The Lenovo T490 also has two USB-C ports, and I want to get a docking station that would work for both devices..

Comment: its 6.75mm from edge to edge Shailen